# Regex that only matches domains name and not subdomains

Tags: regex

I would like to match only domain.com and not subdomain.domain.com in REGEX.

Right now i have this regex

```
/([0-9a-z-]{2,}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3}|[0-9a-z-]{2,}\.[0-9a-z-]{2,3})$/i
```

But it matches the subdomain too. So i would like to skip domains with subdomain and only process the "normal" ones.

Any idea ? Thank you !

Edit: Domains like .co.in, .co.uk etc.... shouldn't not be skipped.

Comment: I dunno I'd it's possible to do it with only regex. Might have to use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
/^[0-9a-z-]+\.(?:(?:co|or|gv|ac)\.)?[a-z]{2,7}$/i
```

Matches only `domain.com`

Changed it a bit, as limiting the TLD to max 3 chars would take something like `.museum` out, or is that intended?

If you really need a more accurate pattern, that would be an awesome long one and regex might not be the best solution for that. As you can see, there are [many tlds](https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List#TLDs_in_the_root_DNS) out there and [even more two-level-tlds](http://george.surbl.org/two-level-tlds) :)

Comment: sub.domain.com gets half matched.

Comment: Nice ! It is what i was looking for ! Adbhishek Goel said something interesting. How to not skip domains like .co.in, .co.uk  ?

Comment: Great, now it's working fine. Now subdomain.domain.com doesn't match, but domain.co.in does ! Thank you !

Comment: @user2914878 It's a rather loose pattern, customize it further to your needs, happy could help :)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you will have to do is explicitly define the domain extensions otherwise it will take

> domain.co.in as subdomain but it is a domain.

so your regex need to have somewhere something like ( com|co.in|co.uk|org|org.in... )

try this ( tried and tested )

```
 ^[0-9a-z-]+\.(?:\.)?(com|com.au|org|org.in|co|co.uk)$
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Dude second thing is regex need to have somewhere something like ( com|co.in|co.uk|org|org.in... ) :P

Comment: Sounds like a continuation, but what about the third thing? Or the rest of a proper answer?

Comment: Thank you guys for you help, unfortunately i can't rep you yet.